# Perror permission denied (shared memory)

Tags: c, memory, shared

I'm trying to use shared memory to pass the struct eq between programs but when I run the progrma I get a permission denied perror. Can anybody give me a reason for this?

```
int shmid = shmget(4567, (size)*sizeof(eq), IPC_CREAT|0666);
printf("%d\n",shmid);    
if (shmid<0)
{
    perror("shmget");
    exit(1);
}
```

Shmid is equal to -1 at the end of my program and it shouldn't. Also i'm running the code on omega, and I use a mac (not sure if this info is relevant).

Comment: `perror` prints the value of `errno`, which is only valid immediately after a failed operation. You're using it wrong.

Comment: Well my main problem is that shmid = -1. Why is it that? It should be a number greater than 0.

Comment: Sounds like you need `ipcs` and `ipcrm`. Either that or change the `key` to some other value. I'm guessing that `sizeof(eq)` has changed.